# NVIDIA HEVC 4k 5.0 level support

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, 4k-resolution, nvidia-quadro

I'm trying to encode a 4K (3840x2160) stream with level less or equal 5.0 with no success.

I'm using ffmpeg latest build, nvidia drivers 410.66. 
All dockerized on nvidia/cuda:8.0-devel-ubuntu16.04 image.

My test command:

```
ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel trace -hwaccel cuvid -c:v hevc_cuvid -analyzeduration 10000000 -probesize 10000000 -y -i "udp://239.1.2.3:1234?pkt_size=1316\&timeout=2500000\&buffer_size=409600\&fifo_size=1000000\&overrun_nonfatal=1" -map i:0x100 -filter:v:0 "scale_cuda=w=3840:h=2160" -c:v:0 hevc_nvenc -profile main -level 150 -preset llhp -zerolatency 1 -cbr 1 -rc cbr_ld_hq -b:v:0 2000k -minrate:0 1500k -maxrate:0 2400k -bufsize:0 1000k -map i:0x101 -c:a copy -f ismv /tmp/test.ismv
```

It has to be less or equal because [Apple specification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices) says:

> 1.6. Profile, Level, and Tier for HEVC MUST be less than or equal to Main10 Profile, Level 5.0, High Tier.

Strange thing is that if I encode with less resolution (HD) it works, but with 4K resolution I get this error:

> InitializeEncoder failed: invalid param (8) 
>   Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder
>   for output stream #0:0 -maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate,
>   rate, width or height

My ffmpeg configure command:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/nv-codec-headers" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include/' --extra-ldflags='-L/usr/local/ffmpeg_build/lib -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64/' --bindir=/usr/local/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-cuvid --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-nvenc --enable-filter=scale_cuda --enable-filter=thumbnail_cuda --enable-libnpp --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
```

Comment: What is the frame rate of the source video?

Comment: Input video: Video: hevc (Main 10), 1 reference frame ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HEVC level 5.0 supports a maximum of 267,386,880 luma samples per second 3840 x 2160 is 8,294,400 samples per frame 8,294,400/267,386,880 = a max of 32 frames per seconds. (see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Video_Coding_tiers_and_levels)

Your video `Video: hevc (Main 10), 1 reference frame ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p10le(tv, bt709), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc` is 50 frames per second.

If you cut the frame rate to 25, it will work. Otherwise you need to level 5.1